# How to limit users to just one default keyboard in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, keyboard

I am having difficulties in limiting users to using just one keyboard. I want to do this to make sure that my users use a whole integer on the number pad. However with the introduction of custom keyboards in iOS 8 it is possible for users to enter decimals. This means that my app tells them that tram 271.334232 is an A-class tram when it doesn't exist. If possible at all, could someone tell me what I need to input and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS 8 you can disable it using this method in the app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier {
    if ([extensionPointIdentifier isEqualToString: UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note that if the user has removed the system keyboard completely, no keyboard will show up.